# Get output redirection part of a running process

Tags: io-redirection, command-history, background-process, nohup, jobs

Sometimes I run jobs, I lose track of which output files I have redirected the output to. How can I get the full command I ran a job with, including the output redirection part?

For example, when I run

```
nohup python3 -c $'from time import sleep;\nfor i in range(100): print(i); sleep(1)' > .test.txt &
```

which should print some stuff to `.test.txt` and run for 100 seconds, and then  run `ps -fp <PID>` or check `/proc/<PID>/cmdline`, I only get

```
python3 -c from time import sleep; for i in range(100): print(i); sleep(1)
```

I've tried some of the solutions on [How to get the command line args passed to a running process on unix/linux systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821837/how-to-get-the-command-line-args-passed-to-a-running-process-on-unix-linux-syste), but I don't think my command is being truncated.

I notice if the shell I ran the command in is still open when the job finishes, it shows the full path, e.g.

```
[1]+  Done                    nohup python3 -c 'from time import sleep;
for i in range(100): print(i); sleep(1)' > .test.txt
```

Is this info only stored in the shell that ran the job?

**Edit:** @muru I just realised `history` does give me my command after all; thanks.

Comment: "... then run ... `history`" - you should get the full command there.

Comment: If you have the pid of the running process then `ls -l /proc/${pid}/fd` will show you where stdout (fd 1) and stderr (fd 2) are being written.

Comment: (1) Yes, redirections are not arguments and thus won't show in `ps` (2) In 'job-control' shells -- the ones that display the completion message you posted, normally at least bash ksh zsh dash tcsh -- the backgrounded jobs _not_ completed yet are listed by the builtin command `jobs` (3) On Linux and some other Unixes, but not all and you didn't say which you want, redirections for _any_ process to which you have access (not only jobs under your shell) can be examined by looking in `/proc/$pid/fd`

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085 @doneal24; I found my output file in `/proc/$pid/fd` :). If you answer below I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the pid of the running process then `ls -l /proc/${pid}/fd` will show you where stdout (fd 1) and stderr (fd 2) are being written.

Comment: Can you please give an example? I get an error that command not valid.

Answer (score -2):

A single '>' will overwrite the file, try using '>>' which appends to the end of the file.

```
[admin@srv1 ~]$ for x in $(seq 1 100); do echo $x >> test.txt; done
[admin@srv1 ~]$ head -n 25 test.txt
1
2
...
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question of `what file was stdout redirected to`.